# Deploy hook for django syncdb not working on openshift

Tags: python, django, openshift, django-syncdb

I created a django app on openshift successfully. But, I'm not able to run syncdb using the following deploy hook.

```
#!/bin/bash
source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python/virtenv/bin/activate
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME
python manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

What could be wrong? Please help!

Comment: Is there any output? errors?

Comment: Nothing as such. When I try to open admin page, it gives error that table does not exist. Here's the link  http://greypic-sids.rhcloud.com/admin/

Comment: I meen errors during `git push`. The only difference with [example django app](https://github.com/openshift/django-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy) is they do `source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python/virtenv/bin/activate`. Are you sure virtualenv path is correct?

Comment: No errors during git push. I've tried replacing `python-2.6` with `python` as well. So, path is correct.

Comment: I SSHed and ran these commands manually and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think its simply because you forget to add the right for file execution with `chmod +x filename`